# Does $f$ being Riemann-integrable on $\mathbb{R}$ implies the same for $1/f$?

Tags: calculus, integration, upper-lower-bounds

If $f(x)$ is integrable and for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) \ne 0$, then is  $1/f(x)$ integrable ?

I tried to prove that by Riemann
or by Darboux's theorem but I couldn’t prove that.

Comment: I hate to nitpick: the adjective is integrable (as in integrable function) and it's Riemann, not "reman."

Comment: Under these conditions -- no. Take $f(x) = x$ if $x \neq 0$ and $f(0) = 1$. Then $1/f$ is unbounded on $[0,1]$ and not Riemann integrable.  If you specify that $0 < m \leqslant f(x) \leqslant M$ everywhere then this has been answered already [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/590279/148510).

Comment: ... and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/257916/148510)